# Remove both items from list of dictionaries if value of 1st key matches

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

```
details = [
{"id": "1", "name": "Bob", "age": 21, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Mary", "age": 25, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "2", "name": "Jeff", "age": 22, "student" : "no"}
]
```

Expected:

```
[{"id": "2", "name": "Jeff", "age": 22, "student" : "no"}]
```

I tried solution for removing duplicates but in those methods id=1 and 2 remains as a unique values, but i need if the id is repeated remove both or multiple matching pairs along with its dictionary and left with only the one which is not repeated. Any help please.

Comment: all the occurrence of duplicate values for "id" key should be removed

Comment: There is no "first" key in a `dict`; unless you use an `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a `list` to check the multiple occurrence of an `id`, then you can ignore that entry

```py
details = [
{"id": "1", "name": "Bob", "age": 21, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Mary", "age": 25, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "2", "name": "Jeff", "age": 22, "student" : "no"}
]

ids = []
to_be_deleted = []

for i in details:
    if i['id'] in ids:
        to_be_deleted.append(i['id'])
    else:
        ids.append(i['id'])

output = [i for i in details if i['id'] not in to_be_deleted]

print(output)
```

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'Jeff', 'age': 22, 'student': 'no'}]
```

Comment: You can use only one of `ids/to_be_deleted`, and making it a `set` will greatly improve performance if there are a lot of dicts in the list

Answer (score 0):

Using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get `ids` appearing one time only.

```
from collections import Counter

details = [
{"id": "1", "name": "Bob", "age": 21, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "1", "name": "Mary", "age": 25, "student" : "yes"},
{"id": "2", "name": "Jeff", "age": 22, "student" : "no"}
]

c = Counter(map(lambda x: x['id'], details))

details = list(filter(lambda x: c[x['id']] == 1, details))

print(details)
```

Prints:

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'Jeff', 'age': 22, 'student': 'no'}]
```